# How to use the Common Navigator Framework with checkboxes

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, cnf

When I use Common Navigator Framework, I can not find how to let it support check boxes just like TreeViewer.

At the beginning, I intend to use Check Tree View, but it can not take full advantage of  RCP mechanism, so I decide use  Common Navigator Framework....

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/165683/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) commented, this question has been [answered on the Eclipse Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/165683/).

In order to create a CommonViewer with check boxes, you need to override
`createCommonViewerObject` like this:

```java
protected CommonViewer createCommonViewerObject( Composite parent ) {
  int treeStyle = SWT.CHECK | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL; 
  return new CommonViewer( getViewSite().getId(), parent, treeStyle ); 
}
```